# Tasks and timesheets in ProjectServer 2013 JSOM

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, jsom, project-server

I have searched a lot online but cannot find any references on how to dive down to task level details and manage/fill timesheets in ProjectServer 2013 using JSOM (Javascript implementation of CSOM). The only references i could find are [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163093.aspx) and  [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj163037.aspx), and they only deal on project level.

I am using JSOM beacuse of the [double hop authentication issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22841115/the-remote-server-returned-an-error-401-unauthorized-using-csom-in-asp-net) i am facing when trying to use CSOM.

Can really use some help here.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

- Check-out a project
- Send a MERGE or PUT request to _api/ProjectServer/Projects('projectid')/Draft/Tasks('taskid')
- Check-in and Publish

If you want to get a list of tasks for a certain project, then send a GET to /ProjectServer/Projects('projGuid')/Tasks

This API endpoint gives you access to actualWork, actualStart, actualFinish, percentWorkComplete and other timesheet properties.

Read more here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj669340.aspx